# WebForm Server.Transfer - Variables are not being recorded in downloaded files

Tags: c#, webforms, server.transfer

I'm using `Server.Transfer` and in the 2nd place I have a number of labels that are updated with a `Request.Form["textbox_text"]`;

This all works really well, but the problem is I also want to write the content in that textbox to file
like a word document using this method

```
Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Word.doc");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application / vnd.ms -word";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

htw.Write("<table><h2><b>[ Text ]</b></h2><br>" + TextBox_name.Text + "</table>");

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

But whenever I check the file it will not have anything written on it. I've even tried to save the value of a Request.Form to a static variable and then write that variable but without any success.

Comment: I have created a web forms site and implemented it exactly as you did, and the document downloads just fine. Can you please give more details as: 1. When opened with a standard text editor (Open With: Notepad) what are the contents of the file? 2. Can you please see the Network tab in the browser's developer tools (F12) and see what is downloaded there? Do you get a HTTP 200 OK, or some error message?

Answer (score 0):

How are you using `Server.Transfer()`? Post that code, make sure you are using the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_Transfer_System_String_System_Boolean_) that preserves the form values:

```
Server.Transfer("page.aspx", true);
```